# Can I make the class with my main method a Singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

I’m making a dbms in Java (really simple dbms just so we learn) at uni, and the instructions are to make my DBManager class a singleton, and this class should also be the « main entry point » of the dbms, so I suppose it has to have the main method in it?

Is it good practice/possible to make this class a singleton, or should I separate my main class from DBManager class and simply call DBManager from the main class?

Answer (score 0):

The main method (publis static void main(String[] args)) is the main entry of the application.

I this the requirements of your exercice is to have a main entry of the dababase management(select create update delete).

Please consider that it more clean to separate the responsabilities.

Here an example, not the best but it will Help you to understand singleton.

```
public class DmbsManager {
    private static DmbsManager dmbsManager = new DmbsManager();

    public static DmbsManager getInstance(){
        return dmbsManager;
    }

    //Below goes all the dababse management methods as select create ...

}
```